# flutter_ffmpeg package name

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, podfile

when installing flutter_ffmpeg I should set the package name in

android/build.gradle

```
 ext {
  flutterFFmpegPackage  = "<flutter ffmpeg package name listed in section 2.1>"
```

}

and in ios/Podfile

```
if plugin_name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
      pod 'flutter_ffmpeg/<package name>',
```

Do I just enter "flutter_ffmpeg" here or is the "package name" different?
How does the final code should look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The package name here is the 'package' you want to include from ffmpeg, below is the list of all package names defined by flutter_ffmpeg:

```
Package Main Release    LTS Release
min min min-lts
min-gpl min-gpl min-gpl-lts
https   https   https-lts
https-gpl   https-gpl   https-gpl-lts
audio   audio   audio-lts
video   video   video-lts
full    full    full-lts
full-gpl    full-gpl    full-gpl-lts
```

for instance you want to involve all the packages, just set the 'package name' to 'full'.